# can we see the context menus on the window without mouse right click?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I'm new to windows programming.

I have created a window and context menu using CreatePopupMenu() and added few items to it.

My question is, Is it possible to view the context menu without mouse click ?

Comment: Are you looking for `TrackPopupMenu[Ex]`, by any chance?

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik No. I have seen a method called "ShowPopUpMenu()". But im not sure how to use it.

Comment: Maybe using keyboard?

Comment: You can use SendMessage with WM_CONTEXTMENU. This simulates the right mouse click.

Answer (score 1):

The function that does what you describe is [`TrackPopupMenu`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms648002.aspx) or [`TrackPopupMenuEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms648003.aspx).